# How to remove duplicate values from a text file?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I know there are a lot of questions related to this, but i couldn't find any useful information. I need to delete duplicate values from the text file.

Here is my text file's text:

```
\ewf54fwe*51-651few15wfe42'
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$names = file('1uzduotistxt.txt');

foreach($names as $name)
{
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($name);$i++) {
        if (is_numeric($name[$i]) && $name[$i]%2==0)
        { 
            echo "$name[$i]";
        }
    }
}
```

My code prints even numbers from the text file (it's: 4642), but i need to remove duplicate values from it. How should i do that? Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is [count_chars():][1]

```
$result = count_chars( $str, 3);
```

With the second parameter $mode set to 3, `count_chars()` will output:

```
 <?php

$names = file('1uzduotistxt.txt');

foreach($names as $name)
{
    $name = count_chars( $name, 3);

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($name);$i++) {
        if (is_numeric($name[$i]) && $name[$i]%2==0)
        { 

            echo "$name[$i]";
        }

    }

}

?>
```

**Output** : `246`

Comment: I've tried that, but it's still does not remove duplicate values... It's still prints '4642' :/

Comment: Man, please, could you insert the count_chars() into my code? Because i don't know where exactly i have to insert it, that's why my code doesn't work or it shows a lot of errors...

Comment: Code updated again.. just copy and paste it...and don't forget to accept the answer if it helped u...(you can accept an answer by clicking on the "tick mark " near answer  then it will turn into green)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of that file in string and then you can fetch integers from that string and then filter them as unique.

```
$str = "\ewf54fwe*51-651few15wfe42";

$arr = array_values(array_unique(str_split(intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $str), 10))));
      print_r($arr);
```